# How to upload remote pdf file into s3 server

Tags: node.js, pdf, amazon-s3, request, node-request

I want to upload remote pdf files into s3 server.

i am using streaming-s3 package for it. Although its working for other websites  but its not working for particular website.(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf)

When i am trying to upload pdf file form https://arxiv.org website then it's not uploading on s3 server.

Here is my code for upload pdf file into s3 server

```
var streamingS3 = require('streaming-s3');
  var awsHeader = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: '1611.10012.pdf',
        ContentType: 'application/pdf',
        ACL: 'public-read'
    };

var url = "https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf";

    var fileReadStream = request.get(url);
   console.log("parsing url : " + url);         
   uploadFile(fileReadStream, awsHeader, cb);


var uploadFile = function (fileReadStream, awsHeader, cb) {   

    //set options for the streaming module
    var options = {
        concurrentParts: 2,
        waitTime: 20000,
        retries: 2,
        maxPartSize: 10 * 1024 * 1024
    };
    //call stream function to upload the file to s3
    var uploader = new streamingS3(fileReadStream, config.aws.accessKey, config.aws.secretKey, awsHeader, options);
    //start uploading
    uploader.begin();// important if callback not provided.

    // handle these functions
    uploader.on('data', function (bytesRead) {
        //console.log(bytesRead, ' bytes read.');
    });

    uploader.on('part', function (number) {
        //console.log('Part ', number, ' uploaded.');
    });

    // All parts uploaded, but upload not yet acknowledged.
    uploader.on('uploaded', function (stats) {
        //console.log('Upload stats: ', stats);
    });

    uploader.on('finished', function (response, stats) {
        console.log(response);
        cb(null, response);
    });

    uploader.on('error', function (err) {
        console.log('Upload error: ', err);
        cb(err);
    });

};
```

I also tried other code for this website, but its also not uploaded the file into s3 server.

```
var options = {
    url: 'https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf',
    headers: {
        'Referer': 'https://arxiv.org',
        'User-Agent': 'stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 5.0)'
    }
}

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  console.log('error:', error);
  console.log('statusCode:', response && response.statusCode);
  uploadFile(body, awsHeader, cb);
});
```

Any Idea why s3 uploading not working for particular website (https://arxiv.org/pdf/1611.10012.pdf) ?

Comment: What is the error message? Perhaps the web site is blocking you.

Comment: No error message, why the website is blocking me. Event it doesn't work on localhost.

Comment: `console.log('error:', error);` doesn't log *anything*?